# Is it possible to blend meshes and have smoothed bevels

Tags: modeling

I just came across this image and was wondering if it's possible to recreate it in Blender. The goal is to make it seem like it's one mesh by having smooth bevels.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, combining two arbitrary objects with a smooth transition between them is tricky, and the best approach heavily depends on what particular shape you are trying to create. However, for the type of shape you show in your question, one relatively easy approach is to use [Metaballs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/modeling/metas/introduction.html):

[image]

This only works for a fairly restrictive set of shapes, but for rounded, liquid-like materials like the one in your question, it can be a nice solution.